# Facebook Error Code 101

Tags: facebook, error-code

Im using Nextscript - SNAP auto-post on website using API-  and got a connection problem after verify my account. i made the app in developer / website .. it verify my facebook login but after that. it gets back to a ERROR:

> ”Error validating application. Application has been
>   deleted.”,”type”:”OAuthException”,”code”:101

For More about Facebook api error codes Facebook API Error Handling.

How can it be deleted when its in my App, running ..
Hope some1 can answer this problem..

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to revisit facebook developers portal to regenerate the SDK and use it to update your script.